# Any tricks for getting an absolutely positioned element inside of a content rail to "snap" to the edge of the viewport without javascript?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: Example image of what I hope to accomplish]

Wasn't quite sure how to word the question succinctly, so I hope the above image helps to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm developing sites using Bootstrap and our designer keeps throwing curveballs at us. At first, the absolute element in the example used to just be a solid color extending to the edge of the viewport--ezpz, just use overflow:hidden somewhere and make the element 9999px wide, no problem. But now we're beginning to use pictures and gradients inside of these suckers, where I will need to know where the edge of the screen is, or otherwise cut off some of the image or only see a portion of the gradient.

**I am fully aware that I am able to accomplish this with JS and some simple math, but I would like to know if there are any solutions using styles that can get the job done.** I tend to develop sites using a very black and white approach wherever possible and view using JS to handle "styling" as a hack, rather than a solution. It feels like I'm brute forcing something that should have a way to finesse it. So I'm more or less just curious if there is a solution that will make my brain a little happier, rather than "how do I do this plz?"

Here's a fiddle, specifically showing the issue with a gradient. Example 1 with solid black works great. Example 2 with a gradient is too wide and basically just looks red (but would look great on a monitor with 20k pixel width!). I'm wondering if there's maybe some clever use of the vw unit that would solve this?

```css
#example1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example1 .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#example1 .relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#example1 .absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#example2 {
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example2 .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#example2 .relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#example2 .absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff0000", endColorstr="#000000", GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="relativeElement">
      <div class="absoluteElement">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="example2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="relativeElement">
      <div class="absoluteElement">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If this question stays open for a while with no css solutions or the community seems to all agree that JS is the way, I will select the top voted answer as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "rail" has a fixed width, this is as simple as a 3-part calc.

> 0.5 * viewport width - 0.5 * rail width + parent container width

E.g.

```
calc(50vw - 150px + 100%);
```

Since your rail width is fixed at 300px and 100% will refer to the full relative element's width because it is fixed.

```css
#example1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example1 .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#example1 .relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#example1 .absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#example2 {
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example2 .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#example2 .relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#example2 .absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(50vw - 150px + 100%);
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff0000", endColorstr="#000000", GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="relativeElement">
      <div class="absoluteElement">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="example2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="relativeElement">
      <div class="absoluteElement">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you David! The numbers had to be tweaked because my example was not 1:1 my situation, but the math makes sense enough for this to click for me. I realized that I was having issues with LESS eating my calc() stuff in styles, so this was definitely two birds with one stone haha.

Answer (score 0):

Because position absolute will snap to the first relatively positioned parents boundary, why not remove the absolutely positioned element from the ***element2*** parent and place a position relative on your ***body***, then set its position left and top relative to the ***body***.

To alleviate having to change the ***height*** and ***top*** properties that will live inside two different elements, set their ***lengths*** to a CSS variable then set each elements properties (the height of the proceeding *example2* element, and the top of the absolutely positioned element you wish to bound to the side of left side of the body) to the CSS variables length. I would do this with both absolutely positioned element and then set their top properties to match that of their parents placements. Then you can change your width to a view port length and your gradient will show up nicely.

Alternately the bubbling up effect of the absolute positioning, you could forgo position relative on your body and adjust according to the HTML element with a few minor adjustments to the left and/or top properties of your absolute elements.

```css
:root {
  --height: 100px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#example1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example1 .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: var(--height);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#example1 .relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.absoluteElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#example2 {
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#example2 .container {
  width: 300px;
  height: var(--height);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#example2 .relativeElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.absoluteElement2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--height);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff0000", endColorstr="#000000", GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="relativeElement">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="absoluteElement">
</div>

<div class="absoluteElement2">
</div>

<div id="example2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="relativeElement">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately making sites for K-12 school districts in USA, so have to deal with Office of Civil Rights for ADA complaints. Not all of them are tech savvy, they just say to "fix things." One of those many things is tabindex order issues. They find a way to complain about links that are floated to the right, so tabbing through them goes right to left instead of left to right... These are issues that schools can lose all federal funding if they don't resolve, no matter how dumb the issue haha. Thank you for the answer regardless though!